# python hash function that returns 32 (or 64) bits

Tags: python

I am looking for a hash function that returns 32 (or 64) bits. I tried md5 from hashlib. For example:

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5(b"H").hexdigest()
```

gives

`c1d9f50f86825a1a2302ec2449c17196`

If there isn't such a hash function, is it possible to extract the leading 32 bits from the hash? I tried:

```
st = hashlib.md5(b"H").hexdigest()
' '.join(format(x, 'b') for x in bytearray(st, 'utf-8'))
```

to convert the hash to binary but it gives:

```
'1100011 110001 1100100 111001 1100110 110101 110000 1100110 111000 110110 111000 110010 110101 1100001 110001 1100001 110010 110011 110000 110010 1100101 1100011 110010 110100 110100 111001 1100011 110001 110111 110001 111001 110110'
```

which can't be right as they all start with two ones.

Comment: You wanted `digest`, not `hexdigest`, so you'd have the raw bytes of the hash. It would also avoid the need to encode the result (`digest` returns raw `bytes` directly).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below I provided four solutions of getting 32/64-bit hashes, as integers, as bytes, as hex, as bits (binary string).

As decimal integers (big endian):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEjsTgjJzOJq6AoM69EA4j10oryc@OTKktSizWgknrFGYlGpmYaSUoeSpp6KZnpqcUlGprRViaxOgrqOZklJTmp6pqaCsoKxka6SZklZJllgW6WmQnIrP//AQ)

```
import hashlib
print(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest()[:4], 'little')) # 32-bit int
print(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest()[:8], 'little')) # 64-bit int
```

Output:

```
3866803524
12578350417885969732
```

---

Instead of integer to get just bytes in little endian order do following:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEjsTgjJzOJq6AoM69EA8rTK85INDI100hS8lDS1EvJTE8tLtHQjLYyidVUUFYwNtJNyizRUTBRSKosSS0mTqsFWKuZCUSrBUTr//8A)

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest()[:4]) # 32-bit, 4 bytes
print(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest()[:8]) # 64-bit, 8 bytes
```

Output:

```
b'D\xbdz\xe6'
b'D\xbdz\xe6\x0fG\x8f\xae'
```

---

Also possible to get 32/64-bit hex values. First variant as little endian hex bytes:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEjsTgjJzOJq6AoM69EA8rTK85INDI100hS8lDS1MtIrUjJTE8tLtHQjLayUIjVVFBWMDbSTcos0VGwUFAASiskZyQWFRNthqEZ2AwzE4gZhmYIM/7/BwA)

```
import hashlib
print(hashlib.sha256(b"H").hexdigest()[:8 ]) # 32-bit, 8  hex chars
print(hashlib.sha256(b"H").hexdigest()[:16]) # 64-bit, 16 hex chars
```

Output:

```
44bd7ae6
44bd7ae60f478fae
```

Second variant as hex numbers (big endian):

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEjsTgjJzOJq6AoM69EIyO1QgNI66UV5efGJ1WWpBZrQBXoFWckGpmaaSQpeShp6qVkpqcWl2hoRluZxOooqOdklpTkpKpramoqKCsYG@kmZZYoAI0h21ALDEPNTGCG/v8PAA)

```
import hashlib
print(hex(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest()[:4], 'little'))) # 32-bit int
print(hex(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest()[:8], 'little'))) # 64-bit int
```

Output:

```
0xe67abd44
0xae8f470fe67abd44
```

---

You can even get bits (binary string) if you want. Bits here are exactly 32 and 64 in count and represented in big endian order.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEjsTgjJzOJq6AoM69EIykzTwNI66UV5efGJ1WWpBZrQBXoFWckGpmaaSQpeShp6qVkpqcWl2ho6iio52SWlOSkqmtqRusaG1lZxWoqKCsYG@kmZZZQxUwzE6iZZiYgM///BwA)

```
import hashlib
print(bin(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest(), 'little'))[-32:]) # 32-bit
print(bin(int.from_bytes(hashlib.sha256(b"H").digest(), 'little'))[-64:]) # 64-bit
```

Output:

```
11100110011110101011110101000100
1010111010001111010001110000111111100110011110101011110101000100
```

---

If you want to count number of leading zeros in binary representation then you may do:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYkxCoAwEAR7X7HdJWiRYJ3HWJx4hZeQnKCvj0FcBoZhy2NH1rX3hgQKYzHEwe9AU6mi5pRvc4I9V8gChihYr5PrZuwaZlAkD9nHldIXvvcX)

```
s = '000010110100101100'
print(next(i for i, e in enumerate(s + '1') if e == '1'))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Don't forget that binary representation of hash above is computed in big endian order meaning that most significant bit is located leftmost. If you need to compute count of zero bits at the least significant bit side then first reverse your string, as below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1jBVkHdAAgMDQyBCEobqHMVFGXmlWgUR1tZ6RrGav7/DwA)

```
s = '000010110100101100'
print(s[::-1])
```

Output:

```
001101001011010000
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What would be the quickest way to count the number of leading zeros in the binary representation?

Comment: @Anush For number of leading zeros you may do [this code](https://tio.run/##LYlBCoAgEEX3neLvNGqhtPYwBRMO1Cg6QZ3eJPo8eDx@fjQmWVrjM6eiiGuNB29DRYBxfd75zm9nhlxY1Ardahl7KuAZBBaQXCeVVclWTDDejOC9XyF8Mbb2Ag). Don't forget that in my answer I computed binary representation in big endian order meaning that most significant bit is located leftmost. If you need leading zeros from LEAST significant side then first you need to reverse binary representation through `s = s[::-1]` like in [this code](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRCEjsTgjJzOJq1jBVkHdAAgMDQyBCEobqHMVFGXmlWgUR1tZ6RrGav7/DwA)